# How to STOP python to complete execution on one operation and then start other process

Tags: python

```
def fun1():
    #something(opens a command window in a folder and run something)
    os.system("start cmd /c omake clean ")
def fun2():
    #something(opens a command window again in the same folder and run something else)
    os.system("start cmd /c omake ")

for dir in list_of_dir:
    os.chdir(dir)
    fun1()
    fun2()
```

#The above structure is just an example, If you see in the for loop the fun1() and fun2() #calls happened simultaneously
#But how can somebody first execute fun1() completely including the closure of command window #and then only move to calling fun2() in python.

#Kindly guide me on this..

#Thank you.

Comment: it might depend on your os but you could search for os.wait()

Comment: I am using windows OS

Comment: os.wait() should work, However it is not good to start a batch from a script you better directly call os.wait("omake clean":) what ever omake does

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid running scripts that way. Also do not name variables like dir.
It helps a lot to get an editor which does some linting

Just an example. Still it would be better to know what you try to achieve ?

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def fun1():
    os.system("dir")
    print('fun1: done!')
    
    
def fun2():
    os.system("dir")
    print('fun1: done!')


path_folder = "c:/Windows"
file_names = [f for f in listdir(path_folder) if isfile(join(path_folder, f))]


for filen_name in file_names:
    os.chdir(path_folder)
    fun1()
    fun2()
```